# WSO2 API Manager startup takes too long

Tags: wso2

Running on WSO2-AM 1.5.0, the log files shows a lot of messages. We run WSO2 for the first time (clean repo database), this works(!). But the next time we start WSO2-AM it does not come up:

```
WARN - CarbonServerManager Carbon initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items:
WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.mediation.configadmin-4.2.0
WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway-1.2.0
WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.localentry-4.2.0
```

What does this mean?

Comment: We increased the min and max heapsize to 2048m. Restarted the server and we saw the system is coming up and running in 104 sec. Still long, but it is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved. It is a bug in the carbon layer. WSO2 Answer:

> When starting up wso2apim-1.6.0 a problem occured in wiring of OSGi
>   bundles. The reason was, under "Import-Package:" section,
>   "javax.xml.soap;version" was specified as "0.0.0". Due to this reason
>   the following issue occured waiting for the services to start. The
>   issue was fixed by specifying the soap versions as
>   "javax.xml.soap;version=1.0.0".

A patch can be obtained from WSO2 if you have a subsciption (WSO2-CARBON-PATCH-4.2.0-0156.zip)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is solved. We are running WSO2 Api Manager on VMWare with Suse EE 64bit on a two node cluster. Each node has 4 cores. We have set the amount of cores back to 1 and the issue is gone.

So, If you run into 100% CPU, and strace shows this, decrease the virtual cores:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 99.68    1.297481         389      3333      1057 futex
  0.31    0.004000         571         7         7 restart_syscall
  0.01    0.000082           0       895           read
  0.00    0.000061           0       366           mprotect
```

...

```
[pid  5185] futex(0x817b54, 0x189 /* FUTEX_??? */, 1, {1392218925, 111990000}, ffffffff) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
[pid  5185] futex(0x817b28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[pid  5185] futex(0x817b54, 0x189 /* FUTEX_??? */, 1, {1392218925, 162159000}, ffffffff) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
[pid  5185] futex(0x817b28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[pid  5185] futex(0x817b54, 0x189 /* FUTEX_??? */, 1, {1392218925, 212338000}, ffffffff <unfinished ...>
[pid  5499] <... futex resumed> )       = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
[pid  5499] futex(0x7f45e04d5728, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[pid  5499] futex(0x7f45e04d5754, 0x189 /* FUTEX_??? */, 1, {1392218930, 203367000},
```

Comment: Issues on Suse SP3 with : Oracle Java 1.7 64bit / NO Issues with : Oracle Java 1.6 64bit, IBM Java 1.7 64bit